# I have jquery code below for the vertical menu and I have 2 tabs as apparels and cosmetics when i hover on apparels tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

find me an answer for this.
 on hover of apparels tab it should show the apparels contents

```
$('#women').hover(function(){
    $('#body').show(10,function(){
           $('#apparelsTab').hover(function(){
            $('#apparels').show(10,function(){
                $('#apparels').hover(function(){
                    $('#apparels').show(10);
                },function(){
                    $('#apparels').hide();
                });
            });
        },function(){
        $('#apparels').hide();
    });

    $('#cosmeticsTab').hover(function(){
        $('#cosmetics').show(10,function(){
            $('#cosmetics').hover(function(){
                $('#cosmetics').show(10);
            },function(){
                $('#cosmetics').hide();
            });
            });
        },function(){
        $('#cosmetics').hide();
        });
    });
    });
```

get me an answer or the link

Comment: create [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put HTML code for us to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#women').on("mouseover", function(){
    $('#body').show(10,function(){
           $('#apparelsTab').hover(function(){
            $('#apparels').show(10,function(){
                $('#apparels').hover(function(){
                    $('#apparels').show(10);
                },function(){
                    $('#apparels').hide();
                });
            });
        },function(){
        $('#apparels').hide();
    });

    $('#cosmeticsTab').on("mouseover",function(){
        $('#cosmetics').show(10,function(){
            $('#cosmetics').hover(function(){
                $('#cosmetics').show(10);
            },function(){
                $('#cosmetics').hide();
            });
            });
        },function(){
        $('#cosmetics').hide();
        });
    });
    });
```